# Docker restart policy is ignored if no space left on device

Tags: docker, docker-compose, production, restart

**Situation:**

- I run docker services on a production server.
- The restart policy ist set to `always`.
- Disk usage of some services is volantile (file sharing service) which means the disk is 100% full from time to time - and there is a delay till it's cleaned up again.

**Problem:**

If a docker service exits while the disk is full, **docker does not try to restart** that service. Even after disk space is available again, the service ist not restart automatically anymore. Manually restarting the service works - but that's not what I want for a production service.

The actual error is:

```
mkdir /var/lib/docker/overlay2/0e609c8b4059d3e0f1273bd8cb9e9a95c3d76730798a391dd360054ac450f3ed/merged: no space left on device
```

**Question:**

Is there a way to keep docker services restarting under ***any*** conditions?

**Logs:**

`docker inspect <service>` (official mongodb service in the following example - other service are similiar)

```
[
    {
        "Id": "b5b54e0dcd8c91b5ead96ce77d2b28afb4b973e205f81a7f6f2fb6b11920f40d",
        "Created": "2022-01-13T08:24:03.142162294Z",
        "Path": "docker-entrypoint.sh",
        "Args": [
            "mongod"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "exited",
            "Running": false,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 0,
            "ExitCode": 133,
            "Error": "mkdir /var/lib/docker/overlay2/0e609c8b4059d3e0f1273bd8cb9e9a95c3d76730798a391dd360054ac450f3ed/merged: no space left on device",
            "StartedAt": "2022-01-21T19:12:56.019305407Z",
            "FinishedAt": "2022-01-21T20:11:37.176315302Z"
        },

...

        "RestartCount": 4,

...

        "HostConfig": {
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "always",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
...
    }
]
```

Comment: I'd treat a full `/var/lib/docker` filesystem as an outage and restart the docker engine when you've recovered from that outage.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, I've not yet found an easy way to monitor the disk, especially if it's only full for a short time. If we got any triggers for that - or a trigger from docker after a restart policy exection failed would be great.